# Recording with fraps

Tags: .net, 2d, record

I'm trying to make a simple 2D game.  The problem is, I went to go record a small demo of it for Youtube and found out that FRAPS can't record it.  I'm using System.Graphics to draw everything, is there a way to make it so my game is picked up by screen recorders.

Comment: Use another recording software, for example Camtasia Studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`System.Graphics` is an encapsulation of GDI+ drawing surface. FRAPS works only with programs that uses OpenGL or DirectX. Instead, you can use one the following programs to record your game:

- [Open Broadcaster Software](https://obsproject.com/) (free and open source)
- [Camtasia Studio](http://www.techsmith.com/camtasia/)
- [BBFlashBack](http://www.bbsoftware.co.uk/bbflashback.aspx)